# Unity 5 Assetbundle for FBX - Model Scale reduced

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, assetbundle

Our Unity (Windows) project was in Unity 4.3.1 and now we are upgrading it to Unity 5.2. In our project we load 3D models (fbx files) as Assetbundles. For the new Unity version when we create assetbundles with Unity 5.2 and load them in Unity, they seems to be really small. It looks like we need to set the Scale factor to around 50 to get it to the orginal size(the size that comes in Unity 4.3)

Was there any change related fbx model size being reduced when creating the asset bundles?

Update - I did a comparison with the 4.3.1 build by changing the Scale factor in 5.2.1. and figured out that when the scale is set to 40, it looks just like in the 4.3.1. But no idea why in Unity 5 the scale get reduced by 40 when creating the asset bundle. If any of you know about this please let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be due to a change in the scale factor in Unity 5. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/916518/3ds-max-imported-mode-scale-issue-with-unity-5.html

So I solved my issue by setting the scale factor to 39.3701 (inches to a meter) when importing models.